# Java, redraw scrolling background image at the same point the last image ends

Tags: java, swing, paint, keylistener, imageicon

My problem is that i have an image which is X in length, and i want to make it so that the image continually scrolls in the background of my game.

In order to do this, and it no be obvious to the player the next background image has to be redrawn at the point at which the previous image ends, this is what i cannot figure out.

Currently i can have continuous redrawing of the image, but just as the old image ends the new image is drawn back at (0,0) so it is obvious that the background is being redrawn.

I know what the problem is, but the solution is avoiding me. The problem is that when i redrawn the image, i reset location to 0. I can't figure out another way to do this currently so maybe someone could help me in someway.

Just a side note the JPanel is 1000 in width.

Here is the code so far:

```
package cje.chris.edwards.game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;


import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    Player player;
    Image background;
    Timer timer;
    private int scrollSpeed, location;

    public Board(){

        player = new Player();
        this.addKeyListener(new Listener());
        setFocusable(true);
        ImageIcon img_ic = new ImageIcon("map.png");
        background= img_ic.getImage();
        location = 0;
        //5 milliseconds
        scrollSpeed = -2;
        timer = new Timer(5, this);
        timer.start();


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //called using timer.start() and its delay
        repaint();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D graphics_2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        //This is the section where my problem lies.
        if(location != 0 && Math.abs(location) % (background.getWidth(null) - 1000)  == 0){
            graphics_2d.drawImage(background, 1000, 0, null);
            location = 0;
        }
        graphics_2d.drawImage(background, location += scrollSpeed, 0, null);
        graphics_2d.drawImage(player.getImage(), 50, 100, null);

        System.out.println(location);
    }

    private class Listener extends KeyAdapter{


        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            scrollSpeed = -1;

            player.move(e);
        }



    }

}
```

Is there a way i can reset location to the end of the last image? so it looks completely seamless. Thanks again!

This is the image i am using, just in case anybody wants to try my code:
https://warosu.org/data/ic/img/0015/95/1385339455019.png

Comment: If you are going to post code. Please post code that does not need fudging.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D graphics_2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    // define bounds by width of image
    while (location > background.getWidth(null)){
        location -= background.getWidth(null);
    }
    while (location < -background.getWidth(null)){
        location += background.getWidth(null);
    }
    // draw image twice to handle any overlap
    graphics_2d.drawImage(background, location += scrollSpeed, 0, null);
    graphics_2d.drawImage(background, location + background.getWidth(null), 0, null);

    System.out.println(location);
}
```